# Ruby - metaprogramming, define_method, DRYing code

Tags: ruby

I created project, in which I have many classes, and every class has a similiar structure:

```
module Project
  class ExampleClass
    attr_accessor :title, :body, :elements_1, :elements_2

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      self.title = attributes[:title]
      self.body = attributes[:body]
      self.elements1 = attributes[:elements1] || []
      self.elements2 = attributes[:elements2] || []
    end

    def ==(other)
      title == other.title && body == other.body && elements1 == other.elements1 && elements2 == other.elements2
    end
  end
end
```

Only differences between classes are its name and names of `elements1` and `elements2` arrays.
My mentor gave me code to DRY my project:

```
module Project
  class Node
    extend ActiveModel::Naming
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :body, :title
    cattr_accessor :element_names
    self.element_names = []

    def element
      element_names.reduce([]) do |name, memo|
        memo + send(name)
      end
    end

    def ==(other)
      body == other.body && title == other.title && element_names.all? { |name| element_by_name(name) == other.element_by_name(name) }
    end

    def element_by_name(name)
      instance_variable_get("@#{name}") || instance_variable_set("@#{name}", [])
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def element(name)
        elements_names << name

        attr_writer name
        define_method(name) do
          element_by_name(name)
        end
      end
    end
    extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

It's quite above my level, I'm trying to make it work - every class should inherit after `Node`. I must somehow pass attributes - `elements1` and `elements2`. I was experimenting with

```
class ExampleClass < Node     
  cattr_accessor :element_names
  self.element_names = [:elements1, elements2]
end
```

in my `ExampleClass` to pass names of arrays.

I also tried with `initialize`, but I can't make it work. I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `element` class method is used to define new elements.

You want something like

```
class ExampleClass < Node
  element :elements1
  element :elements2
end
```

Though there is a serious issue with the code your mentor gave you: the element names are stored in a class variable, which means they will be shared among all subclasses of `Node`. What you want are *class instance* variables.

Replace this

```
cattr_accessor :element_names
self.element_names = []
```

with this

```
def self.element_names
  @element_names ||= []
end
```

that way each subclass stores its own array of element names (and then as a bonus you no longer need any of that `ActiveModel` cruft).